# Simplest hand-rolled permutations and combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

Let's say I have a simple array `["apple", "banana", "lemon", "mango"];`.

Now the simplest handrolled *permutations* of this array, of say choose 3, *with repetition* is:

```js
let array = ["apple", "banana", "lemon", "mango"];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    for (let k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
      console.log(`${array[i]} ${array[j]} ${array[k]}`);
```

Similarly, now *combinations* of this, choose 3, *without repetition* is:

```js
let array = ["apple", "banana", "lemon", "mango"];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++)
  for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length - 1; j++)
    for (let k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++)
      console.log(`${array[i]} ${array[j]} ${array[k]}`);
```

Now I'm wondering, is there a similar simple handrolled approach to generate:

- Permutations without repetition
- Combinations with repetition

Essentially the simplest way like the above examples, without recursion or complex iteration - an analogous way to the generate the other two variants.

Comment: By what criteria do you define "simple"?  This seems like a very broad question.

Comment: Cognitively simple. With simple for loops like the above example, without recursion or complex iteration. Essentially, if there's an analogous way to the generate the other two mentioned using similar methods.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Is it not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the combination with repetition you can simply start second loop from `i` instead of `i+1` and the third one starting from `j` instead of `j+1`. The `+1` is basically what forbids the repetition.

For the permutation is a bit more annoying... for small cases like what you shown you can explicitly check for repetitions:

```
for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<n; j++) {
       if (i !== j) {
           for (let k=0; k<n; k++) {
               if (i !== k && j !== k) {
                   ...
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! thanks, exactly what I was looking for -- wondering if it's possible to lift this as a function which generates these as the algorithms for choose `n`.